# Remove duplicates from a ListView column cast to List

Tags: c#, linq, listview, casting, distinct

Been stuck on something that should be simple, can anybody see the issue?

The idea is this: I have a column in a ListView that I’m converting to a List and I only want Distinct (no duplicate) values…

I thought this should work but I’m getting all the values, including duplicates:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(lvi => lvi.SubItems[2].Text.Distinct().ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueStrings = listView1.Items
  .Cast<ListViewItem>()
  .GroupBy(lvi => lvi.SubItems[2].Text)
  .Select(g => grp.First().SubItems[2].Text)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: the first solution you posted worked:
var uniqueStrings1 = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(lvi => lvi.SubItems[2].Text).Distinct().ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try using a set instead of list, a HashSet would be good, it will not have duplicates.